# how wire a 24 vac normally closed float switch to a relay to turn power on and off to a 120 vac clothes washer

Tags: power-supply, relay

Hi: In over my head just by being here so thanks in advance for your patience and help. My goal is use a 24 vac float switch (which sets in an overflow pan) to interrupt a 120 vac circuit that runs a clothes washer in the event that the washer tub overflows. I kind of get that I need a 24 volt power supply for the float switch and a relay rated for the input and output but I'm not at all sure where to go from there. Thanks for your help. Mike

Comment: Do you have a float switch that will trigger given the limited travel available in an overflow pan?   Probably less than an inch no?  And if you do, is there a 120V version available?   Consider an alternative: A ZWave moisture sensor in the pan, that will react immediately to any overflow without requiring a float to travel any distance plus a Zwave power socket, and a hub you can program to carry out your logic.   This avoids any home made electrical switching gear, allows you to program minimum delays and other logic, and probably will cost about the same as the project you suggest.

Comment: Also, what you really want is not to turn off the power to your washer but to turn off the water to your house.   There are ready-made systems that will do that, you put a sensor under the washer and under toilets etc, and install a smart valve near the meter that reacts to them.  You just buy the whole kit.  More expensive than a few Zwave gizmos but actually achieves what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar problem at my previous house (almost 30 years ago) — washing machine connected to a relatively slow drain pipe. I got a little more sophisticated — I used a low-voltage DC supply connected to a 555 timer that was triggered by the float switch, which in turn drove a solid-state relay. I needed the timer to make sure that the washer stayed powered off for a minimum amount of time (about 60-120 seconds, I forget the exact value) in order to give the pipe time to drain before it restarted.

Of course, this was an "old-fashioned" washing machine with an electromagnetic sequencer — it didn't forget its "state" when the power was interrupted. I'm not sure that "modern" washing machines with microcontrollers will work as well with this scheme.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a normally-closed 120VAC float switch. No need to do 24V.